# Xubuntu 16.04: Active Directory-based user account suddenly stops working

Tags: xubuntu

I have an Active Directory-based user account "andyg", with which I access all of the machines on my local LAN, including several Xubuntu 16.04-based systems as well. The user is thus NOT local to the Linux systems. Since I learned how to authenticate this user on Ubuntu, and also how to add that user to the sudoers, I have never had any issues - until now.

Suddenly, when I opened a terminal the other morning, I found that instead of my "normal" user folder, I was now in a folder one level LOWER, with a QUESTION MARK for its name:
             /home/andyg/?/
instead of:
             /home/andyg/

and I kept getting "I have no name!" as my username at the terminal prompt! I simply can't imagine where that folder, named simply "?", even came from!

Now, I also have a local administrative account on these Linux-based systems as well, and so I re-booted the system and logged in using that local administrative account's credentials. All fine. Then I attempt to change users at a terminal prompt:

```
> su -l andyg
```

and, after being asked for andyg's password (which it accepts without issue) I am once again confronted with the following user prompt:

```
I have no name!@UBSTUD9200:~$
```

, even though if you type:

```
> echo $USER
```

I get "andyg" in response!

Also, I tried to use "sudo" in a command using the andyg account:

```
> sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and I received the following response:

```
sudo: unknown uid 10006: who are you?
```

when this always worked fine in the past!

Next, I thought I'd check the log files, to see if there were any clues in those. In the /var/log/syslog file, there are many many entries stating basically that:

winbindd "failed to find a Unix account for andyg"

, and that:

"User andyg has Primary Group SID (NULL SID), which conflicts with the domain sid"

..., finally ending with

"Failing operation."

Like I said, this all happened quite suddenly, for no reason I can think of! Because I have only basic Linux skills, I have NO IDEA what could have possibly gone wrong, or exactly what I can do about it to resolve this issue.

It seems that the system has SOME of the info about user andyg, but not all? What is it missing, and how can I tell it what it needs to know?

Here is what I get about user "andyg" from the wbinfo -u command:

```
> wbinfo -u
guest
krbtgt
administrator
andyg
nbeam
```

and here is the (relevant) output from the getent passwd command:

```
> getent passwd
... 
andyg:*:10006:10002:Andre R. Gagne:/home/andyg:/bin/bash
```

Here is the (relevant) output from the getent group command:

```
> getent group
...
domain_admins:x:10003:
domain_users:x:10002:
domain_computers:x:10007:
linuxusers:x:10000:
linuxadmins:x:10001:
```

Can anyone help me out here? I would really rather FIX this problem than resort to wiping and re-installing the OS!

PS: I guess I should add that my domain controllers are all Windows Server 2008 R2, basically the "server" version of Windows 7...

Thanks for any help in advance!

ZTagre.

Comment: Okay, so it has been a while, and I see that nobody has come up with anything.